# Dynamic form field with jquery not post values to php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, http-post

i had form that is add some fields via jquery when i click " add new " button it will update a dom , with input fields . Input fields are using a array as a name , when i click submit button , values did not post to php, only static form values are posted but not dynamically generated input values .

My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/4L9Rc/

It will demonstrate clearly how is my form working .

HTML

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form method="POST" action="http://fabtech.com/invoices/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-horizontal re-form form-inv"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="aLngVzB1UIlY6cEedbAh55tirXGGkYJl78BL0CRN">                        <legend>Invoice Details</legend>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Invoice No</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter invoice no" class="form-control" name="inv_no" value=""">
                                                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Invoice date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter text" class="form-control date-pic" name="inv_date" value="">
                                                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Customer</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <select class="form-control" name="inv_customer">
                                    <option value="">- Select Customer -</option>
                                                                            <option value="suresh">suresh</option> 
                                                                            <option value="ABC210">ABC210</option> 
                                                                            <option value="QWERTy123DF">QWERTy123DF</option> 
                                                                            <option value="CUS002">CUS002</option> 
                                                                            <option value="CUS0023">CUS0023</option> 
                                                                            <option value="CUS003">CUS003</option> 
                                                                        </select> 
                                                                </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">PO No</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" class="form-control" name="po_no" value="">
                                                                </div> </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">PO date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" class="form-control date-pic" name="po_date" value="">

                                                                </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Vendor code</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Vendor Code" class="form-control" name="vendor_code" value="">
                                                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">75% abatement value</label>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control sf" name="sf"> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 sfbox" style="display:none">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control sfboxval" readonly="">

                            </div>                             </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">25% Taxable Value</label>

                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control tf" name="tf"> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 tfbox" style="display:none" >
                                <input type="text" class="form-control tfboxval" readonly="">

                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tax in %</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control tax" name="tax" value="">
                                                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Grand Total</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control grandtotal" readonly="" name="grand_total">
                                                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <legend>Particulars

                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" id="apm"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add new</a>

                </legend>
                <table id="apmr" width="69%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover invoice">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="3%">SL No</th>
                            <th width="25%">Description</th>
                            <th width="8%">Unit</th>
                            <th width="8%">Qty</th>
                            <th width="10%">Unit rate</th>
                            <th width="9%"> Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="roo">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="center">  1 </td>
                            <td class="tr_nt"><input type="text" name="parti[1][desc]" class="part"></td>
                            <td class="tr_nt"><input type="text" name="parti[1][unit]" class="part"></td>
                            <td class="tr_qty into"><input type="text" name="parti[1][qty]" class="part qty"></td>
                            <td class="tr_urate into"><input type="text" name="parti[1][urate]" class="part ur"></td>
                            <td class="tr_amt"><input type="text" name="parti[1][amount]" readonly="" class="part tot"></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">

                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                Particular's Total: Rs <span class="parttotal"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>

                </table>
                <p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 5px;"><input name="submit" class="btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" value="View Invoice"></p>


                </form>                </div>
        </div>

    </div>    
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//invoice particulars 
var val;
$("#apm").click(function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    //var preData = $("#apmr tr:last").html();
    //console.log(preData);
    //
    //$("#apmr tr:last").after('<tr>' + preData + '</tr>');
    var lasttd = $('.roo tr:last td:first').text();
    val = parseInt(lasttd) + 1;
    $(".roo tr:last").after(' <tr>  <td valign="center">  ' + val + ' </td> <td class="tr_nt"><input type="text" name="parti[' + val + '][desc]" class="part"></td> <td class="tr_nt"><input type="text" name="parti[' + val + '][unit]" class="part"></td>    <td class="tr_qty into"><input type="text" name="parti[' + val + '][qty]" class="part qty"></td>  <td class="tr_urate into"><input type="text" name="parti[' + val + '][urate]" class="part ur"></td> <td class="tr_amt"><input type="text" name="parti[' + val + '][amount]" readonly class="part tot" ></td></tr>');
    //  val = val + 1;
    return false;
})

var gt;
$("table.invoice").on("change", '.qty, .ur', function(event) {
    calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
    calculateTotal();
});
function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('.qty').val();
    var qty = +row.find('.ur').val();
    row.find('.tot').val((price * qty).toFixed(2));
}
function calculateTotal() {
    var Total = 0;
    $("table.invoice").find('.tot').each(function() {
        Total += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".parttotal").text(Total.toFixed(2));
    calgrand();

}
$(".re-form").on('change', '.tax,.tf,.sf', function(event) {
    calgrand();
})
function calgrand() {
    var taxVal = $('.tax').val();
    var parVal = $(".parttotal").text();
    var result = parVal - taxVal * parVal / 100;
    $('.grandtotal').val(result.toFixed(2));
    if ($('.tf').is(':checked')) {

        var resulttf = parVal - 25 * parVal / 100;
        $('.tfboxval').val(resulttf.toFixed(2));
        var result = result - resulttf;
        $('.grandtotal').val(result.toFixed(2));


    }
    if ($('.sf').is(':checked')) {
        //alert('entered');
        var resultsf = parVal - 75 * parVal / 100;
        $('.sfboxval').val(resultsf.toFixed(2));
        var result = result - resultsf;
        $('.grandtotal').val(result.toFixed(2));
    }
}


$('.tf').click(function() {
    $(".tfbox").toggle(this.checked);
});
$('.sf').click(function() {
    $(".sfbox").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

in php i had

```
print_r($_POST['parti']);
```

its give out put

```
Array
(
 [1] => Array
    (
        [desc] => 
        [unit] => 
        [qty] => 
        [urate] => 
        [amount] => 
    )

)
```

but i need

```
Array
(
 [1] => Array
    (
        [desc] => 
        [unit] => 
        [qty] => 
        [urate] => 
        [amount] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [desc] => 
        [unit] => 
        [qty] => 
        [urate] => 
        [amount] => 
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [desc] => 
        [unit] => 
        [qty] => 
        [urate] => 
        [amount] => 
    )
```

....
    )

javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please indent your code next time. Too many changes to make in your form. At the line where you have "Enter invoice no." you have left an open quote at `value="""` which is a big mistake.

Overwrite your HTML code with this:

```
<div class="matter">
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="http://fabtech.com/invoices/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-horizontal re-form form-inv">
        <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="aLngVzB1UIlY6cEedbAh55tirXGGkYJl78BL0CRN">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <legend>Invoice Details</legend>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Invoice No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter invoice no" class="form-control" name="inv_no" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Invoice date</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" class="form-control date-pic" name="inv_date" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Customer</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <select class="form-control" name="inv_customer">
                                <option value="">- Select Customer -</option>
                                <option value="suresh">suresh</option>
                                <option value="ABC210">ABC210</option>
                                <option value="QWERTy123DF">QWERTy123DF</option>
                                <option value="CUS002">CUS002</option>
                                <option value="CUS0023">CUS0023</option>
                                <option value="CUS003">CUS003</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">PO No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" class="form-control" name="po_no" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">PO date</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" class="form-control date-pic" name="po_date" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Vendor code</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Vendor Code" class="form-control" name="vendor_code" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">75% abatement value</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control sf" name="sf">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 sfbox" style="display:none">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control sfboxval" readonly="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">25% Taxable Value</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control tf" name="tf">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 tfbox" style="display:none">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control tfboxval" readonly="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tax in %</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control tax" name="tax" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Grand Total</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control grandtotal" readonly="" name="grand_total">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <legend>Particulars <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" id="apm"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add new</a>
            </legend>
            <table id="apmr" width="69%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover invoice">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="3%">
                    SL No
                </th>
                <th width="25%">
                    Description
                </th>
                <th width="8%">
                    Unit
                </th>
                <th width="8%">
                    Qty
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    Unit rate
                </th>
                <th width="9%">
                     Amount
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="roo">
            <tr>
                <td valign="center">
                     1
                </td>
                <td class="tr_nt">
                    <input type="text" name="parti[1][desc]" class="part">
                </td>
                <td class="tr_nt">
                    <input type="text" name="parti[1][unit]" class="part">
                </td>
                <td class="tr_qty into">
                    <input type="text" name="parti[1][qty]" class="part qty">
                </td>
                <td class="tr_urate into">
                    <input type="text" name="parti[1][urate]" class="part ur">
                </td>
                <td class="tr_amt">
                    <input type="text" name="parti[1][amount]" readonly="" class="part tot">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                     Particular's Total: Rs <span class="parttotal"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </table>
            <p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 5px;">
                <input name="submit" class="btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" value="View Invoice">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Your mistake was that your `<form>` tag was closed in the wrong place. Remember to always place tags in such a way that always the inner tags close first.

Comment: @user007 nice ... i understood